# For AspNetCore, where can I get the extension which contains UseOwn?

Tags: .net-core, owin, nancy

I am trying trying to get a self-hosted Nancy application running on .Net Core.

This article shows how to get Nancy running on .Net Core:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringAMinimalWebAPIWithNETCoreAndNancyFX.aspx

But this is the code which will not compile:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Nancy.Owin;

namespace NancyApplication
{
   public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy());
        }
   }
}
```

*UseOwin* is simply not recognized at all.  I think it must be an extension, but I cannot find what nuget package contains it.

On the Nancy issues in GitHub, there is this question asking about .Net Core slef hosting:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2858

And the "answer" references as an example this Project:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/samples/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Kestrel/Program.cs

But this project is .Net Framwwork, not Core.

It really does not help that Nancy docs and examples are a random mixture of Nancy 1.4 vs 2.0 and .Net Core and Framework.

Does anyone have a good working example?  Heck, with .Net Core, just one .csproj and one .cs file would explain it all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin/) NuGet pacakge. That's where `UseOwin` is.